# Python does not see pygraphviz

Tags: python, installation, pygraphviz

I have installed pygraphviz using easy_install
But when i launch python i have an error:

```
>>>import pygraphviz as pgv
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pygraphviz
>>>
```

Using Ubuntu 12.04 and gnome-terminal.

Comment: Have you used virtulenv, if so can you please confirm if the environment on which you installed the package is the same from which you may be calling script or invoking shell?

Comment: I dont know if i have used virtulenv. How to check if i have installed pyhraphviz and python on the same environment?

Comment: I just typed easy_install pyhraphviz

Comment: Ok do the following in your gnoe-terminal 1. `pip install virtualenv` 2. `virtualenv myenv` 3. `source myenv/bin/activate` 4. `pip install pygraphviz` Then run python and try `import pygraphviz` as check if it works.

Comment: Also take a look at this nice [Tutorial](http://www.clemesha.org/blog/modern-python-hacker-tools-virtualenv-fabric-pip/) on pip and virtualenv when you have time.

Comment: I dont have pip installed. apt-get does not contain it either.  And apt-get does not contain virtualenv

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install python-pip python-virtualenv`

Comment: After "pip install pygraphviz":

Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /home/sashko/src/webkit2/webkit/Tools/Scripts/myenv/build/pygraphviz
Storing complete log in /home/sashko/.pip/pip.log

Comment: OSError: Error locating graphviz.

Comment: Just curios did you do `sudo apt-get install graphviz` before you're doing `pip install pygraphviz`. In my case I was missing that, on my local VM.

Comment: yes, i did sudo apt-get install graphviz before doing pip install pygraphviz.

Comment: How to find out where "graphviz" was installed? And were it should be installed so that pyhraphviz setup.py could find it?

Comment: Ok I figure the issue. You might be missing libgraphviz-dev. You can install it using `sudo apt-get install libgraphviz-dev`. You can check  if graphviz is installed using `dpkg -l | grep 'graphviz'`

Comment: Worked! Will it work only in myenv?

Comment: Yes it would. Give it a try.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Assuming that you're on Ubuntu please look at following steps

1. `sudo apt-get install graphviz libgraphviz-dev pkg-config`
2. Create and activate [virtualenv](http://www.clemesha.org/blog/modern-python-hacker-tools-virtualenv-fabric-pip/) if needed. The commands looks something like `sudo apt-get install python-pip python-virtualenv`
3. Run `pip install pygraphviz`
4. Run terminal and check by importing and see if it works

Comment: Yes, `pkg-config` is important, otherwise `pip install pygraphviz` will can not be compiled, cause `library_path`.

Comment: `ImportError: undefined symbol: Agundirected `, as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32885486/import-pygraphviz-not-working-ubuntu).

Comment: make sure you restart your terminal...so your changes gets affected

Answer (score 20):

On Ubuntu 14.04, there is a problem in auto detecting graphviz library and include files. If you follow the steps below probably you'll be safe.

```
1) sudo apt-get install graphviz libgraphviz-dev pkg-config python-pip
2) pip install pygraphviz --install-option="--include-path=/usr/include/graphviz" --install-option="--library-path=/usr/lib/graphviz/"
```

Comment: Thanks for this, also works for me on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS when trying to install pygraphz via pip

Comment: These install options also worked for me experiencing the same error on macOS (having run `brew install graphviz`), except the path was `/usr/local/include/graphviz` and the lib was `/usr/local/lib/graphviz`, so full command was: `pip3.6 install pygraphviz --install-option="--include-path=/usr/local/include/graphviz/" --install-option="--library-path=/usr/local/lib/graphviz”`.

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04, I could pull it off with just `sudo apt-get install graphviz libgraphviz-dev graphviz-dev` followed by `pip install pygraphviz`

Comment: also works in ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I needed this in order to install it ..

Answer (score 16):

I use mac m1, I fix this by this.

```
#install graphviz first
brew install graphviz

#check your graphviz path   
brew info graphviz

#change to your dir
export GRAPHVIZ_DIR="/usr/local/Cellar/graphviz/<VERSION>" #3.0.0 in my case

#finally run this 
pip install pygraphviz --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I$GRAPHVIZ_DIR/include" --global-option="-L$GRAPHVIZ_DIR/lib"
```

Comment: Thank you for this, was the only solution that worked. Just needed to change `GRAPHVIZ_DIR` to my local HomeBrew path

Comment: With more recent versions: export GRAPHVIZ_DIR=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/graphviz/7.1.0/

Comment: For me it worked to use the command from the note from the [docs](https://pygraphviz.github.io/documentation/stable/install.html#homebrew):
`pip install --use-pep517 \
            --config-setting="--global-option=build_ext" \
            --config-setting="--build-option=-I$(brew --prefix graphviz)/include/" \
            --config-setting="--build-option=-L$(brew --prefix graphviz)/lib/" \
            pygraphviz`

Answer (score 15):

The quick and easy solution is:

```
sudo apt-get install -y python-pygraphviz
```

using pip will also work, but make sure you have graphviz, libgraphviz-dev, and pkg-config already installed.

```
sudo apt-get install -y graphviz libgraphviz-dev pkg-config python-pip
sudo pip install pygraphviz
```

Comment: Why are these needed? Installing (and using) python-pygraphviz seemed to work fine for me without libgraphviz-dev. Why then is this needed in advance if its not an explicit  dependency, and  why the others?

Comment: this was answered almost 3 years ago, its possible that they've changed how pygraphviz is packaged by now so that this is not all necessary. If that's the case, you should post an answer here to that effect.

Comment: Thanks! For me just installing `python-pygraphviz` fixed the problem

Answer (score 15):

On Mac OSX, the following did the trick for me:

```
pip install graphviz
pip install cgraph
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig 
cd /usr/local/include/graphviz 
sudo ln -s . graphviz 
pip install pygraphviz
```

[As suggested, fixed typo from previously /urs/local/ to /usr/local/]

Comment: Worked for me in combination with pydot2 installation + but replace in above instructions 'urs' by 'usr'

Comment: How would this work in a virtual environment?

Answer (score 4):

On Mac OSX El Capitan, Bart Theeten's solution works but there are two things you need to be careful. Initially, make sure that you installed graphviz on your computer. You can use homebrew:

```
brew install graphviz
```

Other thing is to make sure you add the path of packages to PYTHONPATH

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

Answer (score 3):

Under Ubuntu 15.10+ (ie 2015ish Debian), the quick and easy solution is:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pygraphviz
```

Any dependencies are properly pulled by apt.

Answer (score 3):

This is the only command that worked for me on my M1 MacBook Pro (MacOS 14.2.1):

```
python3 -m pip install -U --no-cache-dir  \
        --config-settings="--global-option=build_ext" \
        --config-settings="--global-option=-I$(brew --prefix graphviz)/include/" \
        --config-settings="--global-option=-L$(brew --prefix graphviz)/lib/" \
        pygraphviz
```

Credit to this [guy here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76153979/8795001)

Answer (score 0):

In Colab,

```
!apt  install  libgraphviz - dev
!pip install pygraphviz
```

Credits: https://gist.github.com/korakot/a80c04a1945b06e2f4a053f92fecfbf9