# pygraphviz, ImportError: undefined symbol: Agundirected

Tags: python, ubuntu, import, pygraphviz

```
import pygraphviz

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygraphviz/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from .agraph import AGraph, Node, Edge, Attribute, ItemAttribute, DotError
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygraphviz/agraph.py", line 26, in <module>
    from . import graphviz as gv
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygraphviz/graphviz.py", line 28, in <module>
    _graphviz = swig_import_helper()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygraphviz/graphviz.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_graphviz', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygraphviz/_graphviz.so: undefined symbol: Agundirected
```

**I have already tried**

```
pip install pygraphviz --install-option="--include-path=/usr/include/graphviz" --install-option="--library-path=/usr/lib/graphviz/"
```

**I have also tried this answer but still not working**

[Python does not see pygraphviz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661384/python-does-not-see-pygraphviz)

Comment: The error is caused by the graphviz library failing to load a dynamic library - check if the library actually exists, and be sure to run ldconfig to update paths to dynamic libraries if the graphviz directory isn't there.

Comment: can you pls help me to check whether actually the library exists?also how to run idconfig

Comment: @midhunj Use `sudo ldconfig`. It still doesn't work for me.

Comment: I have tried ldconfig.Still it is not working.

Comment: When iam trying to import graphviz, its working fine.Then can any one explain why pygraphviz is not getting  imported?

Answer (score 12):

First of all, uninstall your current module:

```
 pip uninstall pygraphviz
```

then check your paths with:

```
 pkg-config --libs-only-L libcgraph
 pkg-config --cflags-only-I libcgraph
```

That commands should tell the path to the library, for example:

```
-I/usr/include/graphviz
```

Then, using the path from the above output, run [within your virtualenv] the command:

```
pip install pygraphviz --install-option="--include-path=/usr/include/graphviz" --install-option="--library-path=/usr/lib/graphviz/"
```

Source: https://github.com/pygraphviz/pygraphviz/issues/71

Comment: `install-option` twice? Why's that?

Comment: Never mind the output from `pkg-config --libs-only-L libcgraph`. In my case (Ubuntu 16.04) that command returns an emtpy line, and that is exactly the reason why pip doesn't detect the correct path for the graphviz library.
In my case I just installed using:

`pip install pygraphviz --install-option="--include-path=/usr/include/graphviz" --install-option="--library-path=/usr/lib/graphviz/"`

and then it worked.

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu 14.04 @Martin0x777's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32885486/pygraphviz-importerror-undefined-symbol-agundirected#answer-33508561) did not work for me. So I installed pygraphviz from [github instructions](https://github.com/pygraphviz/pygraphviz/blob/master/INSTALL.txt) and the error is gone:

```
git clone https://github.com/pygraphviz/pygraphviz.git
cd pygraphviz
python setup.py install
```