# howto install pygraphviz on windows 10 64bit

Tags: python, 64-bit, windows-10, pygraphviz

Has anyone succeeded in installing pygraphviz on windows 10 64bit? I tried anaconda with python 3.5 64bit & 32bit with no success.

Here is the error I am getting with python 3.5 32bit on win10 64bit

```
python -m pip install pygraphviz --install-option="--include-path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\include" --install-option="--library-path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\lib"
```

Error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\include" -IC:\Users\tra20\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\tra20\Anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /Tcpygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.5\Release\pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.obj
graphviz_wrap.c
pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c(3321): warning C4047: 'return': 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'Agsym_t *'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\lib" /LIBPATH:C:\Users\tra20\Anaconda3\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\tra20\Anaconda3\PCbuild\win32 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86" cgraph.lib cdt.lib /EXPORT:PyInit__graphviz build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.obj /OUT:build\lib.win32-3.5\pygraphviz\_graphviz.cp35-win32.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\pygraphviz\_graphviz.cp35-win32.lib
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'cgraph.lib'
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1181
```

I assume it has something to do with the fact graphviz is linked in 32bit?

Note - I tried all binary for pygraphviz i could found on internet(anaconda,internet), and none work on win10 64bit... if you have any working (i mean you realy tested it ) i would be also happy ...

Comment: [\[SO\]: Installing pygraphviz on Windows 10 64-bit, Python 3.6 (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45093811/installing-pygraphviz-on-windows-10-64-bit-python-3-6/54890705#54890705).

Comment: its solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59707234/issues-installing-pygrahviz-fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-include-file-graph) for windows 10

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start reading from here
https://github.com/pygraphviz/pygraphviz/issues/58

At the bottom of that page there is a link to a x64 zip file in Github (like [this](https://github.com/mahkoCosmo/GraphViz_x64/blob/master/graphviz-2.38_x64.tar.gz))
Unpack that. Create a coresponding Program Files folder for your x64 file and put them there

Then install using this

```
pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-IC:\Program Files\Graphviz2.38\include" --global-option="-LC:\Program Files\Graphviz2.38\lib\" pygraphviz
```

Comment: Here's the link at the bottom of that issues page: https://github.com/mahkoCosmo/GraphViz_x64/. What's strange is that the repo hasn't been updated in 8 months but the `release` directory you're pointing towards in `\Graphviz2.38\lib` doesn't exist.

Comment: In my case (Win 10, Python 3.6), additionalIy, had to apply a patch described here https://github.com/pygraphviz/pygraphviz/issues/74#issuecomment-238323405

Comment: This throws `'graphviz/cgraph.h' : No such file or directory`.

Comment: This works for me, but it does not work if I try to specify these options in the `requirements.txt` file and then read the `requirements.txt`  file inside the `setup.py` file to specify the `install_requires`. I get an parse error at `--global-option`.

Answer (score 46):

I've created a build of PyGraphviz 1.5 on my [Anaconda channel](https://anaconda.org/alubbock/pygraphviz) for Windows 64 bit running Python 3.6 through 3.9. If you're running [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/), you can install with:

```
conda install -c alubbock pygraphviz
```

This will also install Graphviz 2.41 as a dependency (don't install it separately, it might conflict and not all versions are 64-bit compatible).

I don't currently have a version for Python 3.5 or 32-bit versions of Windows, but I hope the above helps.

Comment: saved me a lot of time. Thanks :)

Comment: This is slightly wrong, and does not work for me. I used `conda install -c alubbock graphviz pygraphviz`

Comment: @Julio I've just added a Python 3.8 build. Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: this worked for me on windows 10. do `dot -c` after installation

Comment: It didn't include neato. How do I get that to install with graphviz?

Comment: Unfortunately lack of neato is a [known issue](https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/issues/1753) in the graphviz Windows release. Hopefully they'll resolve that soon.

Comment: @lubstep You, my man, are an angel. I am so grateful!

Comment: Worked like a charm on Python 3.8! Super great time saver.

Answer (score 12):

The accepted answer didn't work for me running Python 2.7 (Anaconda) on Windows 10. The file path that @MiniMe suggested for `--global-option` didn't even exist in the git repo that he or she pointed to.

What did work for me was following instructions provided by the (currently) bottom answer to: [Installing pygraphviz on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571067/installing-pygraphviz-on-windows?rq=1)

Steps:
1. Download graphviz-2.38.msi from https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Download/Download_windows.html and install
2. Download the 2.7 o̶r̶ ̶3̶.̶4̶  wheel file you need from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygraphviz
3. Navigate to the directory that you downloaded the wheel file to
4. Run `pip install pygraphviz-1.3.1-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl`
5. Rejoice

N̶o̶t̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶m̶i̶g̶h̶t̶ ̶h̶a̶v̶e̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶r̶u̶n̶ ̶`̶p̶i̶p̶ ̶i̶n̶s̶t̶a̶l̶l̶ ̶p̶y̶g̶r̶a̶p̶h̶v̶i̶z̶-̶1̶.̶3̶.̶1̶-̶c̶p̶3̶4̶-̶n̶o̶n̶e̶-̶w̶i̶n̶_̶a̶m̶d̶6̶4̶.̶w̶h̶l̶`̶ ̶i̶f̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶'̶r̶e̶ ̶t̶r̶y̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶g̶e̶t̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶w̶o̶r̶k̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶ ̶P̶y̶t̶h̶o̶n̶ ̶3̶.̶4̶.̶ ̶I̶ ̶d̶i̶d̶n̶'̶t̶ ̶t̶e̶s̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶o̶u̶g̶h̶.̶  Also, the SO answer I referenced also mentioned needing to add graphviz to your `PATH` but I didn't need to. Good luck!

Update: The python3 wheel vanished. If you're running python3, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40528048/pip-install-pygraphviz-no-package-libcgraph-found/42315670#42315670) worked for me. Follow step 1 above and then in WSL bash run:
 1. `sudo apt-get install python-dev graphviz libgraphviz-dev pkg-config`
 2. `pip install pygraphviz`

That answers says to use `sudo pip install pygraphviz`, but that gave me a dreaded pip import error for some reason. Dropping the sudo made it work in my case.

Comment: No quite sure why this got a zero score, but it worked for me as well.

Comment: THe answer I provided was for Python 3.X this is the answer for 2.7

Comment: If you're trying to use pygraphviz on windows 10 bash instead, this answer worked for me (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40528048/pip-install-pygraphviz-no-package-libcgraph-found/42315670#42315670). Basically, just run: `sudo apt-get install python-dev graphviz libgraphviz-dev pkg-config` then `sudo pip install pygraphviz`

Comment: @r3robertson. where is the python 3.x file? i only see `cp27` 32 and 64 bit versions.

Comment: @jason I couldn't find the 3.x wheel on that site anymore either. I updated my answer with what worked for me on 3.6. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: @r3robertson. Thanks. Hopefully someone can find it... i posted a bounty here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45093811/installing-pygraphviz-on-windows-10-64-bit-python-3-6. I even updated to visual studio 14 and it still doesn't install.

Comment: @jason Did you try using that other answer? I don't think I ever got it to work with Anaconda btw, I made a virtual environment via WSL, installed pygraphviz on that, and ran a jupyter notebook through that virtual environment.

Comment: Your python3 link isn't even relevant to windows

Comment: This comment gave me the way to install (**python v3.8**, Win10x64):  
1. install https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Download/Download_windows.html  
2. add to path C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin  
3. download https://github.com/CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries/blob/master/PyGraphviz/v1.5/Graphviz-2.42.2/pygraphviz-1.5-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl  
4. run `pip install pygraphviz-1.5-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl`   
5. profit

Comment: was missing those additional libraries on ubuntu 22. installing them allowed me to install pygraphviz on python 3.10. Thank you

Answer (score 7):

None of the above worked for me, so I will show what did worked on my windows 11 machine (I don't think the windows version was the problem), which is in the [pygraphviz documentation](https://pygraphviz.github.io/documentation/stable/install.html):

1. Install Visual C/C++, from here: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
   It shows up as a requirement and even if you did install it and try to reinstall with pip, it may not work because garphviz is another requirement.
2. Download and install graphviz for windows: [stable_windows_10_cmake_Release_x64_graphviz-install-2.46.0-win64.exe](https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/package_files/6164164/download)
3. Restart your computer (as required per the first step)
4. Then install the library pygraphviz through Windows PowerShell with the following command (I don't know why, with pip it still wasn't working):

> ```
> python -m pip install --global-option=build_ext `
>           --global-option="-IC:\Program Files\Graphviz\include" `
>           --global-option="-LC:\Program Files\Graphviz\lib" `
>           pygraphviz
> ```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It is a real pain to install pygraphviz on Windows 10 but this is the simples solution which works for me:

Step 1: Download and install Graphviz

https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Download/Download_windows.html

Step 2: Add below path to your PATH environment variable

C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin

Step 3: Re-open command line and activate venv in your project, example:

venv\Scripts\activate

Step 4: Download binaries from below link:

https://github.com/CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries/tree/master/PyGraphviz/v1.5/Graphviz-2.42.2

Step 5. Install whl into your virtual environment

For example:

In case of python 3.7

pip install pygraphviz-1.5-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl

In case of python 3.8

pip install pygraphviz-1.5-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl

Comment: thank you, your comment about **adding the Graphviz path to the PATH environment variable** is what finally got this working for me

Comment: NOTICE: This does *NOT* work for `python version > 3.8`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I installed 64 bit PyGraphViz for Windows 10:

Downloaded and installed GraphViz from https://www2.graphviz.org/Packages/stable/windows/10/cmake/Release/x64/graphviz-install-2.44.1-win64.exe

Made sure I had Visual C++ installed, e.g. from here:
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Then I ran:

```
pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-IC:\Program Files\Graphviz 2.44.1\include" --global-option="-LC:\Program Files\Graphviz 2.44.1\lib" pygraphviz
```

Then I had to add `C:\Program Files\Graphviz 2.44.1\bin` to my system path before `import pygraphviz` worked.

Finally, I had to run this in command prompt after the install to register plugins and be able to draw graphs: `"C:\Program Files\Graphviz 2.44.1\bin\dot.exe" -c`

Obviously, for a  newer version of Graphviz you'll need to check and update all the paths given above.

Answer (score 2):

The true easiest way to install pygraphviz on Windows without conda or external packager is to use Gohlke's wheels (opinion: His works should be assumed daily by someone in the Python Software Foundation)

1. Install latest or adapted graphviz package from  [graphviz](https://graphviz.org/download/#windows) using the 64bit or 32bit exe. Don't forget to check the box "add to the path"
2. Restart the computer
3. Download [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages by Christoph Gohlke from the Laboratory for Fluorescence Dynamics, University of California, Irvine.](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pygraphviz)
4. Open a terminal/powershell as admin on the folder where you downloaded the pygraphviz-*version*-*python_version*-*win_version*.whl and enter `pip install pygraphviz-*version*-*python_version*-*win_version*.whl`
5. Test the install by opening in the terminal/powershell and entering

   python

   import pygraphviz

if no error returns, pygraphviz is installed and functional

Answer (score 0):

Try to install from your Anaconda (Python 3.8 recommended) environment using:

`conda install -c conda-forge python-graphviz`

Answer (score 0):

From these answers graphviz version worked for me is

https://www2.graphviz.org/Packages/stable/windows/10/cmake/Release/x64/graphviz-install-2.44.1-win64.exe

after that I got an error :

kerras plot model AssertionError: "dot" with args ['-Tps', '..\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp334nlu__'] returned code: 1

followed below steps to fix :

1.Open CMD with administrator privileges (simply right click on the CMD and click "run as administrator")

2.Insert the command dot -c, this will configure the GraphViz plugins

Answer (score -1):

If all the solutions above failed, you can still clone directly from the pygraphviz repository

1. Visit: https://github.com/pygraphviz/pygraphviz.git
2. Download/Clone it
3. put the folder into C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages
4. Change directory to “pygraphviz”
5. Run “python setup.py install” to build and install
6. (optional) Run “python setup_egg.py nosetests” to execute the tests

Source: http://pygraphviz.github.io/documentation/pygraphviz-1.3.1/install.html

Comment: In the step 5, I have the error : basetsd.h not found. Any idea ?