# Issues installing pygrahviz "fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'graphviz/cgraph.h': No such file or directory"

Tags: python, pygraphviz

I'm unable to install pygraphviz even after installing graphviz and ensuring that cgraph.h is present in the directory.

I've also manually specified the directory for install. e.g. install-path

fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'graphviz/cgraph.h': No such file or directory

Looking for any and all suggestions. Using Windows.

```
C:\Users\mmcgown\Desktop\School\MSDS452\pygraphviz-1.5>python setup.py install --prefix=C:\Program_Files_(x86)\Graphviz2.38 --include-path=C:\Program_Files_(x86)\Graphviz2.38\include\ --library-path=C:\Program_Files_(x86)\Graphviz2.38\lib\
```

```
running install
running build
running build_py
running egg_info
writing pygraphviz.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to pygraphviz.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to pygraphviz.egg-info\top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'pygraphviz.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching '*.png' under directory 'doc'
warning: no files found matching '*.html' under directory 'doc'
warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'doc'
warning: no files found matching '*.css' under directory 'doc'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '.svn' found anywhere in distribution
no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\build'
writing manifest file 'pygraphviz.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
building 'pygraphviz._graphviz' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -IC:\Program_Files_(x86)\Graphviz2.38\include\ -IC:\Users\mmcgown\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\mmcgown\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcpygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.obj
graphviz_wrap.c
pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c(2987): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'graphviz/cgraph.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.24.28314\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [howto install pygraphviz on windows 10 64bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40809758/howto-install-pygraphviz-on-windows-10-64bit)

Answer (score 28):

I installed the latest graphviz using the latest win64 executable from graphviz.org

[graphviz 2.49 win64](https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/4207231/packages/generic/graphviz-releases/2.49.0/stable_windows_10_cmake_Release_x64_graphviz-install-2.49.0-win64.exe)

then installation using the following command worked for me

```
pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-IC:\Program Files\Graphviz\include" --global-option="-LC:\Program Files\Graphviz\lib" pygraphviz
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: @KevinRamirezZavalza Let me know in comments if you face any issues in the future

Comment: Worked for me using the latest graphviz at the time of writing (7.1.0)

Comment: didnt work for me
      pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c(2711): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'graphviz/cgraph.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.35.32215\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pygraphviz
Failed to build pygraphviz
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pygraphviz, which is required to install

Comment: @PraveerKumar Please make sure you have visual studio and necessary build tools installed

Comment: @codeslord Thanks for the suggestions. I had installed vs2022 community version but it did not work. Finally, I just thought to install via anaconda , and it worked for me . I really dnt know what was screwed up :(

Comment: @PraveerKumar (just for anyone following this) I was able to install it from [PyGraphViz Install Guide](https://pygraphviz.github.io/documentation/stable/install.html), but their command for Windows has little error. You need to remove the extra double quote before -I
--config-setting="--global-option=-IC:\Program Files\Graphviz\include"

Answer (score 19):

On Ubuntu please do
`sudo apt install graphviz-dev`

Answer (score 7):

For those who visit this page, you may already come across to this [fix](https://github.com/tan-wei/pygraphviz) or this [issue](https://github.com/pygraphviz/pygraphviz/issues/155) on GitHub and try to install GraphViz2.38 manually. But neither of them will work since GraphViz and PyGraphViz are 2 different libraries

Mac or Ubuntu already have their solutions on GitHub, however for Win10 64-bit, it does not receive any fix yet since 2018. [Installing pygraphviz on Windows 10 64-bit, Python 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45093811/installing-pygraphviz-on-windows-10-64-bit-python-3-6)

Someone have created a build of PyGraphviz 1.5 on his [Anaconda channel](https://anaconda.org/alubbock/pygraphviz) for Windows 64 bit running Python 3.6, Python 3.7 or Python 3.8. If you're running Anaconda, you can install with:

```
conda install -c alubbock pygraphviz
```

Please mark this as a possible duplicate with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40809758/howto-install-pygraphviz-on-windows-10-64bit) if someone see it.

Comment: `conda install -c alubbock pygraphviz` this worked on Windows 10