# Cannot install pygraphviz: fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'graphviz/cgraph.h': No such file or directory

Tags: python, command-line, graphviz, pygraphviz

Yes, I know a discussion is here: [Issues installing pygrahviz "fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'graphviz/cgraph.h': No such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59707234/issues-installing-pygrahviz-fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-include-file-graph)

But none of these solutions worked.

I used:

`pip install graphviz`

and also:

`pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-IC:\Program Files\Graphviz\include" --global-option="-LC:\Program Files\Graphviz\lib" pygraphviz`

But neither of these have worked still returning:

`pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c(3020): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'graphviz/cgraph.h': No such file or directory error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.36.32532\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code`

Also there is this warning in the command prompt but i don't know how to utilise it.

`DEPRECATION: --build-option and --global-option are deprecated. pip 23.3 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to use --config-settings. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11859 WARNING: Implying --no-binary=:all: due to the presence of --build-option / --global-option.`

Answer (score 1):

**pip install graphviz** installs a python interface to the Graphviz software system, but not the Graphviz software itself.
https://pypi.org/project/graphviz/ says:

> To render the generated DOT source code, you also need to install Graphviz

Go here to get the Graphviz download:  https://graphviz.org/download/

Comment: I already installed graphviz but i'll try it again, is there a specific version I should get?

Comment: start **cmd** & type **dot -V**  If you get a response with the release version, that is not the problem.

Comment: Right t i got a version, any ideas what the issue could be?

Comment: 1. does **C:\Program Files\Graphviz\include** exist and is it populated with good files?  2. I wonder about the forward slash in `'graphviz/cgraph.h'`

Comment: It does infact exist  and i can see the `cgraph.h` file as well :/ , I don't think the "/" should matter though