# plotting tensorflow model with plot_model in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, graphviz

Trying the example of the [plot_model doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/plot_model)

```
input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(100,), dtype='int32', name='input')
x = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(
    output_dim=512, input_dim=10000, input_length=100)(input)
x = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='output')(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input], outputs=[output])
dot_img_file = '/tmp/model_1.png'
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, to_file=dot_img_file, show_shapes=True)
```

But it returns this message

> You must install pydot (`pip install pydot`) and install graphviz (see instructions at https://graphviz.gitlab.io/download/) for plot_model to work.

I installed (with `pip install` in the jupyter console) and verified (with `pip show`) the installation of libraries :
Name: pydot
Version: 1.2.3
Name: graphviz
Version: 0.20.1
Name: pydotplus
Version: 2.0.2

I can import the packages in the Notebook but still the same message.

Answer (score 0):

Common problem, note that the message you quote says:
`and install graphviz (see instructions at https://graphviz.gitlab.io/download/) for plot_model to work.`
There are *two* packages that need to be installed (unfortunately *both* are named Graphviz)
If you haven't already, go to The indicated link, download, and install the appropriate version.
Also see [Cannot install pygraphviz: fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'graphviz/cgraph.h': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76655533/cannot-install-pygraphviz-fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-include-file-graphvi/76655862#76655862)