# Preventing Overlap of edges and nodes with NetwrokX/Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, networkx

I am trying to plot numbers of a problem "Collatz Conjecture" which forms a nice network between numbers(node labels). However, in the final plot of the solution using networkx `nx.spring_layout(G)` I get overlapping edges and nodes:
[image]
[image]

The nx.spring_layout is configured(through trial and error) as:

```
 pos=nx.spring_layout(G,k = 0.004, iterations = 500, scale = 0.6)
 nx.draw(G, labels=labels, pos=pos, font_size = 6, alpha = 0.5, node_size = nodes.values())
 plt.show()
```

Is there a particular way to prevent this overlap, given that there is adequate empty space in the plotting window? Node size in this case is dictated by the value of:`len(G.neighbors(node))`
No node has more that 3 neighbours and the max node size is capped at 300 to further prevent overlap.
The odd thing is that for the longer branches this seems to be handled fairly well, but for branches such as [24,12,6,3,10] as in the images, it fails to demarcate this branch sufficiently, in other cases it overlaps altogether. Please advise if I should use another layout besides `nx.spring_layout(G)` which might handle this better.

Comment: `graphviz_layout` is usually doing the best job. (`from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import graphviz_layout`.)

Answer (score 1):

Picking up on the really helpful comment from DYZ about using `graphviz_layout()`, I thought I'd share my experience here, in case anyone else is having a similar issue, because getting this set up wasn't totally straightforward (for me, at least, on Ubuntu 16.04):

I found `sudo pip install pygraphviz` didn't work, because it couldn't find one of the files it needed. I then tried `sudo apt-get install graphviz libgraphviz-dev pkg-config` followed by `sudo pip install pygraphviz` (thanks to [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661384/python-does-not-see-pygraphviz)), which *looked* like it worked (i.e. installation succeeded), but I still couldn't use `graphviz_layout()` through NetworkX. So, I uninstalled `pygraphviz` (`sudo pip uninstall pygraphviz`) and installed it again as follows (thanks to a tip on [this thread](https://github.com/pygraphviz/pygraphviz/issues/71)):

`sudo pip install pygraphviz --install-option="--include-path=/usr/include/graphviz" --install-option="--library-path=/usr/lib/graphviz/"`

This *did* work, and visualisations with `graphviz_layout()` do seem to have less node overlap than using NetworkX's `spring_layout()`, as well as a more æsthetically pleasing approach to edge length and cluster spacing.

Comment: Thanks, I'd shelved the project because I couldn't figure it out, will give this a run...