# Alter edge length and cluster spacing in networkx/matplotlib force graph

Tags: python, d3.js, matplotlib, graph, networkx

I'm trying to use python to output a PNG of a force graph using networkx and matplotlib. Here's what it currently looks like:

[image: networkx/matplotlib force graph]

The nodes overlap quite a lot, the edge length is very short, and the clusters are very sparse.

Here's what happens if I visualise the same graph using d3.js (ignore the different colours, edge weights, and arrows, which I'm *not* trying to reproduce):

[image: d3.js force graph]

As you can see, this is much more 'legible' and visually appealing, because the nodes are spaced out better, and the clusters are closer together, leaving less white space.

Despite reading every topic I could find here and trying several dozen iterations with node size, figure size, edge weight, and an edge `length` property (that doesn't seem to do anything, but that might be because it's an arbitrary property), I can't make the matplotlib graph look anything like the d3.js one, even though both graphs were created with exactly the same nodes, node sizes, and edges.

Unfortunately, creating them all in d3.js isn't really an option, as I'm hoping to create tens of thousands of static PNGs, and I don't really fancy rendering them all in my browser then screenshotting them!

So, my question is: **is there (a) a way to improve the matplotlib layout (by making edges longer, and/or avoiding node overlap, and/or decreasing whitespace), (b) a way to output a d3.js force graph to PNG (or any static format), or (c) another library I could use to output better formatted force graphs as images?**

Comment: Update: I have tried the `iterations` parameter, which shows what I presume are different points in the animation of the graph, e.g.:

`pos = nx.spring_layout(G, iterations=100)
nx.draw(G, pos)`

This _might_ be useful, but I'm not totally sure how I'd work out what number of iterations is ideal for different sized graphs... and, again, d3.js does this all automatically.

Comment: Also, I'd love to understand why someone downvoted this post, given it very clearly outlines the problem and the question!

Comment: Probably related to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53156709/2912349

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a way to make this work, by using `graphviz_layout()` rather than `spring_layout()` (thanks to a tip found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46031272/preventing-overlap-of-edges-and-nodes-with-netwrokx-matplotlib/48260769#48260769)). This requires installing some extra libraries, so I'll document what I did (on Ubuntu 16.04) in case anyone else is having a similar issue.

To use `graphviz_layout()`, you have to import it first (`from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import graphviz_layout`). However, you also need to install `pygraphviz`, which seemingly isn't installed as a dependency.

To get `pygraphviz` installed in a way that NetworkX could see it, I needed to do as follows (thanks to a post on [this thread](https://github.com/pygraphviz/pygraphviz/issues/71)):

`sudo pip install pygraphviz --install-option="--include-path=/usr/include/graphviz" --install-option="--library-path=/usr/lib/graphviz/"`

Visualisations with `graphviz_layout()` seem to have less node overlap than `spring_layout()`, as well as much more æsthetically pleasing spacing in general. See below for output (compare to the first image in the question post):

[working networkx/matplotlib/pygraphviz force graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSsPl.png)

This took a lot of fiddling around to get right, so I hope it's helpful for others with similar requirements!