# Lots of edges on a graph plot in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, visualization, igraph

I have following script:

```
import pandas as pd
from igraph import *

df_p_c = pd.read_csv('data/edges.csv')

...

edges = list_edges
vertices = list(dict_case_to_number.keys())

g = Graph(edges=edges, directed=True)

plot(g, bbox=(6000, 6000))
```

I have 2300 edges with rare connection. This is my plot of it:
[image: all area]
And here are zooms of a few parts of it:

[image]
[image]

This plot is not readable because the distance between edges is too small. How can I have a bigger distance between edges? Only edges from the same 'family' have small distance.

Is there any other way to improve plots with a lot of edges? 
I'm looking for any way to visualize parent-child correlation, it could be another python packet.

Comment: Do you really want to visualize **all** the nodes in this graph? Personally, I would compute the connected components (`igraph.Graph.decompose`) excluding all subgraphs with less than `n` nodes, where `n` is at least 2 (thus removing the single nodes) but probably larger. Then I would play around with a few layout options, which are all listed under `igraph.Graph.layout`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You seem to have a lot of small, disconnected components. If you want an informative graph, I think you should sort and group the connected components by size. Furthermore, the underlying assumption of many network layout algorithms is that there is a single giant component. Hence if you want sensible coordinates, you will often need to compute the layout for each component separately and then arrange the components with respect to each other. I would re-plot your graph in this way:

[image]

I have written the code for this graph using `networkx` as that is my module of choice. However, it would be very easy to substitute the `networkx` functions with `igraph` functions. The two functions that you need to replace are `networkx.connected_component_subgraphs` and whatever you want to use for the `component_layout_func`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx


def layout_many_components(graph,
                           component_layout_func=networkx.layout.spring_layout,
                           pad_x=1., pad_y=1.):
    """
    Arguments:
    ----------
    graph: networkx.Graph object
        The graph to plot.

    component_layout_func: function (default networkx.layout.spring_layout)
        Function used to layout individual components.
        You can parameterize the layout function by partially evaluating the
        function first. For example:

        from functools import partial
        my_layout_func = partial(networkx.layout.spring_layout, k=10.)
        pos = layout_many_components(graph, my_layout_func)

    pad_x, pad_y: float
        Padding between subgraphs in the x and y dimension.

    Returns:
    --------
    pos : dict node : (float x, float y)
        The layout of the graph.

    """

    components = _get_components_sorted_by_size(graph)
    component_sizes = [len(component) for component in components]
    bboxes = _get_component_bboxes(component_sizes, pad_x, pad_y)

    pos = dict()
    for component, bbox in zip(components, bboxes):
        component_pos = _layout_component(component, bbox, component_layout_func)
        pos.update(component_pos)

    return pos

    
def _get_components_sorted_by_size(g):
    subgraphs = list(networkx.connected_component_subgraphs(g))
    return sorted(subgraphs, key=len)


def _get_component_bboxes(component_sizes, pad_x=1., pad_y=1.):
    bboxes = []
    x, y = (0, 0)
    current_n = 1
    for n in component_sizes:
        width, height = _get_bbox_dimensions(n, power=0.8)

        if not n == current_n: # create a "new line"
            x = 0 # reset x
            y += height + pad_y # shift y up
            current_n = n

        bbox = x, y, width, height
        bboxes.append(bbox)
        x += width + pad_x # shift x down the line
    return bboxes


def _get_bbox_dimensions(n, power=0.5):
    # return (np.sqrt(n), np.sqrt(n))
    return (n**power, n**power)


def _layout_component(component, bbox, component_layout_func):
    pos = component_layout_func(component)
    rescaled_pos = _rescale_layout(pos, bbox)
    return rescaled_pos


def _rescale_layout(pos, bbox):

    min_x, min_y = np.min([v for v in pos.values()], axis=0)
    max_x, max_y = np.max([v for v in pos.values()], axis=0)

    if not min_x == max_x:
        delta_x = max_x - min_x
    else: # graph probably only has a single node
        delta_x = 1.

    if not min_y == max_y:
        delta_y = max_y - min_y
    else: # graph probably only has a single node
        delta_y = 1.

    new_min_x, new_min_y, new_delta_x, new_delta_y = bbox

    new_pos = dict()
    for node, (x, y) in pos.items():
        new_x = (x - min_x) / delta_x * new_delta_x + new_min_x
        new_y = (y - min_y) / delta_y * new_delta_y + new_min_y
        new_pos[node] = (new_x, new_y)

    return new_pos


def test():
    from itertools import combinations

    g = networkx.Graph()

    # add 100 unconnected nodes
    g.add_nodes_from(range(100))

    # add 50 2-node components
    g.add_edges_from([(ii, ii+1) for ii in range(100, 200, 2)])

    # add 33 3-node components
    for ii in range(200, 300, 3):
        g.add_edges_from([(ii, ii+1), (ii, ii+2), (ii+1, ii+2)])

    # add a couple of larger components
    n = 300
    for ii in np.random.randint(4, 30, size=10):
        g.add_edges_from(combinations(range(n, n+ii), 2))
        n += ii

    pos = layout_many_components(g, component_layout_func=networkx.layout.circular_layout)

    networkx.draw(g, pos, node_size=100)

    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    test()
```

### EDIT

If you want the subgraphs tightly arranged, you need to install rectangle-packer (`pip install rectangle-packer`), and substitute `_get_component_bboxes` with this version:

```
import rpack 

def _get_component_bboxes(component_sizes, pad_x=1., pad_y=1.):
    dimensions = [_get_bbox_dimensions(n, power=0.8) for n in component_sizes]
    # rpack only works on integers; sizes should be in descending order
    dimensions = [(int(width + pad_x), int(height + pad_y)) for (width, height) in dimensions[::-1]]
    origins = rpack.pack(dimensions)
    bboxes = [(x, y, width-pad_x, height-pad_y) for (x,y), (width, height) in zip(origins, dimensions)]
    return bboxes[::-1]
```

[image]

### Edit #2

I have written a library for visualising networks, which is called [netgraph](https://github.com/paulbrodersen/netgraph). It automatically handles networks with multiple components in the way outlined above. It is fully compatible with networkx and igraph Graph objects, so it should be easy and fast to make great looking graphs of graphs (at least that is the idea).

[image]

```
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

# installation easiest via pip:
# pip install netgraph
from netgraph import Graph

# construct the graph as before:
g = nx.Graph()

# add 30 unconnected nodes
g.add_nodes_from(range(30))

# add 15 2-node components
g.add_edges_from([(ii, ii+1) for ii in range(30, 60, 2)])

# add 10 3-node components
for ii in range(60, 90, 3):
    g.add_edges_from([(ii, ii+1), (ii, ii+2), (ii+1, ii+2)])

# add a couple of larger components
n = 90
for ii in [10, 20, 40]:
    g.add_edges_from(itertools.combinations(range(n, n+ii), 2))
    n += ii

# if there are any disconnected components, netgraph automatically handles them separately
Graph(g, node_layout='circular', node_size=1, node_edge_width=0.1, edge_width=0.1, edge_color='black', edge_alpha=1.)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Great answer! 
Here's my adaptation to `igraph`: https://gist.github.com/grst/db3f7a5c5b5780b6df7be863983f5f9d

Answer (score 0):

You could checkout [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/), which is a pretty nice graph library. Networkx has [direct plotting support for matplotlib](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/drawing.html).

It supports various layout types, for example [spring layout, random layout, and a few more](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/drawing.html)

You should especially look at [spring layout](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.spring_layout.html#networkx.drawing.layout.spring_layout), which has a few interesting parameters for your use-case:

> k (float (default=None)) – Optimal distance between nodes. If None the
> distance is set to 1/sqrt(n) where n is the number of nodes. Increase
> this value to move nodes farther apart.

Or both of these in combination with a custom layout:

> pos (dict or None optional (default=None)) – Initial positions for
> nodes as a dictionary with node as keys and values as a coordinate
> list or tuple. If None, then use random initial positions.
>
> fixed (list or None optional (default=None)) – Nodes to keep fixed at initial
> position.

The edge weight might also be something you can tune in order to get results you like:

> weight (string or None optional (default=’weight’)) – The edge
> attribute that holds the numerical value used for the edge weight. If
> None, then all edge weights are 1.

I would recommend combining networkx with [bokeh](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/index.html), which is a new plotting library that creates web-based html/js plots. It has direct support for [networkx](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/graph.html), and has some nice features like easy integration of node hover tools. If your graph isn't too big, the performance is pretty good. (I've plotted graphs with about 20000 nodes and a few thousand edges).

With both libraries combined, all you need is the following bit of code for a simple example (from the documentation) that tries to build an optimized layout:

```
import networkx as nx

from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models.graphs import from_networkx

G=nx.karate_club_graph()  # Replace with your own graph

plot = figure(title="Networkx Integration Demonstration", x_range=(-1.1,1.1), y_range=(-1.1,1.1),
              tools="", toolbar_location=None)

graph = from_networkx(G, nx.spring_layout, scale=2, center=(0,0))
plot.renderers.append(graph)

output_file("networkx_graph.html")
show(plot)
```

Comment: Playing with the `k` parameter will do nothing for OP as the problem are the unconnected components, which will contract compared to everything else if you apply a force directed layout, the result of which you can see in the plot above (igraph's default is also the spring layout): nicely spaced components, terribly spaced nodes. The **average** distance between nodes is great though. /s

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what meaning you are looking for?  Or are you exploring?  Or is this a specific question about zooming issues?

So far, you have done a good job of seeing the overall structure.  Some ideas you might consider making new vocabulary with a few routines to support it.  For example, if you make a *small cluster* be the set of points and edges that are together, then you can plot histograms, visualizations of clusters overlayed on each other, compare clusters with and without long nodes, and so one.