# Visualize Nodes and Their Connections via networkx

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, networkx

I have a list of Connections between two nodes describing similarities of Entries in a Dataset.

I'm thinking of vizualising the Entries and their connections to show that there are clusters of very similar entries.

Each tuple stands for a pair of very similar nodes. I've chosen weight as 1 for all of them since it's required but I want all edges equally thick.

I've started with `networkx`, problem is I don't really now how to cluster the similar nodes together in a useful manner.

I have a List of the connections in a Dataframe:

```
smallSample = 
[[0, 1492, 1],
 [12, 937, 1],
 [16, 989, 1],
 [18, 371, 1],
 [18, 1140, 1],
 [26, 398, 1],
 [26, 1061, 1],
 [30, 1823, 1],
 [33, 1637, 1],
 [54, 1047, 1],
 [63, 565, 1]]
```

I Create a graph the following way:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.Graph()
for index, row in CC.iterrows():
      G.add_edge(CC['source'].loc[index],CC['target'].loc[index], weight =1)
pos = nx.spring_layout(G, seed=7)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=5)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=G.edges(), width=0.5)
pos = nx.spring_layout(G, k=1, iterations=200)
plt.figure(3, figsize=(2000,2000), dpi =2)
```

With the small sample provided above the result looks like this:

[image: Small Sample]

The result from my real df which consists of thousands of points:

[image: Big Sample]

How can I Group the linked nodes together so that it is better visible how many of them are in each cluster? I dont want them to overlap so hard, its really not that easy to grasp how many of them are there specially in the big sample.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data, a draft of your required output and provide an example of the code that does not work.

Comment: I have made some suggestions on how to layout graphs with many components in this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53156709/2912349).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.